# View call of plot object in ggplot2::qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot element, called "p":

```
p <- qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, 
facets=gear~cyl, main="Scatterplots of MPG vs. Horsepower",
xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
```

I then call "p" and get a plot.

How do I call p so that I see the assignments to the variable:

```
>somefunction(p)

qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, 
facets=gear~cyl, main="Scatterplots of MPG vs. Horsepower",
xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
```

Comment: Which variable? Please clarify your question. Are you looking for 
`ggplot_build`?

Comment: `p$mapping` will tell you `x` and `y`. `p$layers` will give you the layers. You want to reconstruct the whole call?

Comment: Yes, is there a simple way to reconstruct the call?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Roland, I would like to see the statements assigned to p

Comment: I lost the call and am just looking for the simplest way to reconstruct it

Comment: I would look at `unclass(p)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use function `summary()` that will show data (names of all variables in data frame), mappings of values and what kind of faceting is used as well as which geom is used.

```
 summary(p)
data: mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb [32x11]
mapping:  colour = am, shape = am, x = hp, y = mpg
faceting: facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) 
-----------------------------------
geom_point:  
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```